# Tensor products and Residue fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

> Given a ring homomorphism between two Noetherian rings, $f:A \to B$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal in $B$ and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be an ideal in $A$ such that $f^{-1}(P) = \mathfrak{p}$.  How can we prove the following:

$$B_P \otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p}) = B_P/\mathfrak{p}B_P$$

Comment: Always try to work out some example first. For example, try $A=k$ a field, $B=k[x]$ a polynomial ring in $x$ and $P=xB$. See what you get.

Comment: Given $S = A \setminus \mathfrak{p}$, is localising $(B/\mathfrak{p}B)_{f(S)}$ the same as $B_P/\mathfrak{p}B_P$. Isn't $f(S) \subsetneq B\setminus P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let for instance $A$ be a field, and $P$ a prime ideal of $B$ (then $\mathfrak{p}=0$) such that $B\neq B_P$.